# getting errors while making a serial connection using Netmiko - i've tried /dev/ttyS , ttyS , COM1 but no luck

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

Getting following errors while connecting via Serial using Netmiko

1. I am using OpenSUSE
2. Using Netmiko to connect to Cisco 2960 switch
3. the script uses a text file called commands.ios to read and execute them after serial connection is made like  - `show ip int brief`, show `cdp neigh`, etc..

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import serial

with open('commands.ios') as f:
    commands_list = f.read().splitlines()

ios_device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios_serial",
    "port": "ttyS8",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "password",
    "serial_settings": {
        "baudrate": 9600,
        "bytesize": serial.EIGHTBITS,
        "parity": serial.PARITY_NONE,
        "stopbits": serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    },
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios_device)
output = net_connect.send_config_set(commands_list)
print(output)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "configserial.py", line 25, in <module>
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios_device)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 326, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/cisco/cisco_ios.py", line 17, in __init__
    return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 250, in __init__
    self.port = int(port)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ttyS8'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the COM port in `serial_settings` and you should also set `fast_cli` to `False`.

```py
ios_device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios_serial",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
    "secret": "cisco",
    "fast_cli": False,  # add this line
    "serial_settings": {
        "baudrate": serial.Serial.BAUDRATES[12],  # 9600
        "bytesize": serial.EIGHTBITS,  # 8
        "parity": serial.PARITY_NONE,  # 'N'
        "stopbits": serial.STOPBITS_ONE,  # 1
        "port": "COM3",  # define your COM port here (for example COM3 on Windows or /dev/ttyUSB0 on GNU/Linux)
    },
}
```

A complete working demo should look like the following

```py
import serial
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios_serial",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
    "secret": "cisco",
    "fast_cli": False,  # add this line
    "conn_timeout": 30.0, # add this line as well
    "serial_settings": {
        "baudrate": serial.Serial.BAUDRATES[12],  # 9600
        "bytesize": serial.EIGHTBITS,  # 8
        "parity": serial.PARITY_NONE,  # 'N'
        "stopbits": serial.STOPBITS_ONE,  # 1
        "port": "COM3",  # define your COM port here
    },
}

with open(file="commands.ios", mode="r") as f:
    commands_list = f.read().splitlines()

print("Connecting...")
with ConnectHandler(**device) as conn:
    print("Connected")
    if not conn.check_enable_mode():
        conn.enable()
    output = conn.send_config_set(commands_list)
print(output)
```

Comment: in my Linux Box I cannot see anything as such /dev/ttyUSB0. I can only see /dev/ttyS8 which works perfectly with pyserial but in this snip of code /dev/ttyS8 is not working I've also tired /dev/ttyUSB8 but no luck.

Comment: @DeathS7roke You can find port number on Linux: 1. Open terminal and type `ls /dev/tty*`. 2. Figure out which port you are connected to from the output and use in the snip.

Comment: when I am issuing ls /dev/tty* it is giving me the following output:- ls /dev/tty*
/dev/tty      /dev/ttyS110  /dev/ttyS126  /dev/ttyS141  /dev/ttyS157  /dev/ttyS172  /dev/ttyS188  /dev/ttyS30  /dev/ttyS46  /dev/ttyS61  /dev/ttyS77  /dev/ttyS92
/dev/tty0     /dev/ttyS111  /dev/ttyS127  /dev/ttyS142  /dev/ttyS158  /dev/ttyS173  /dev/ttyS189  /dev/ttyS31  /dev/ttyS47  /dev/ttyS62  /dev/ttyS78  /dev/ttyS93
/dev/tty1     /dev/ttyS112  /dev/ttyS128  /dev/ttyS8... etc. and many more.   
but I know for the Fact that my actual port number is /dev/ttyS8. but "Port" : "/dev/ttyS8" in my script ?

Comment: you set at the first dictionary ( "device_type": "cisco_ios_serial" ) but at the end you stet ( ConnectHandler(**ios_device)). these *** device type *** should be same.